# Add a picture in Word from VBA without it moving with the text added after it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've added the picture to the word document and when I try to add text on lines below it on the document, the picture is moved by the text being printed behind it instead.

How can I add the picture so that it doesn't move to the right when additional text is added but at the same kept in line with the text getting printed above it?

Comment: You could use a table to align things?

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to use a VBA macro recorder available in Word so you could do all the necessary steps manually and then get the code required generated for you automatically?